# Responsive navigation doesn't align on each other

Tags: html, css

I have a nav seperated into two divs. One div for left side and another div for right side, coz I wanted to make a big gap in the center between them. So left nav has float: left; and the right one has float: right; and looks just like that:

`HOME  ABOUT                         PORTFOLIO CONTACTS`
Now when I want it to be responsive and stack on each other nicely in the center once the screen gets smaller than 650px size, this is what happens: it centers in the center, but HOME and ABOUT links are positioned a bit more on the left and CONTACTS, PORTFOLIO are positioned a bit further on the right. But I want them all 4 to stack equally on each other. To be aligned nicely. I tried clear: both; but didn't help. Looks like this:

`HOME
 ABOUT
  PORTFOLIO 
  CONTACTS`

But I want it to be like:

`HOME
 ABOUT
 PORTFOLIO
 CONTACTS`

What do I do?

This is the code:
HTML:

```
<div class="menu-small">
<div class="menu-left">
<ul>
<li><a class="a-menu-left" href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a class="a-menu-left" href="#">ABOUT</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="menu-right">
  <ul>
<li><a class="a-menu-right" href="#">PORTFOLIO</li>
    <li><a class="a-menu-right" href="#">CONTACTS</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-left {
font-family: "roboto", "sans-serif";
}

.menu-right {
font-family: "roboto", "sans-serif";
} 

.a-menu-left {
text-decoration: none;
color: #555555;
float: left;
margin-left: 40px;
padding-right: 70px;
}

.a-menu-right {
color: #555555;
float: right;
margin-right: 75px;
padding-left: 40px;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #222211;
cursor: pointer;
}

li {
list-style-type: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:650px) {
.menu-small {
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;



 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linked a fiddle with a responsive menu. https://jsfiddle.net/Dneilsen22/wvLf18we/2/

Remove the width from your last bit of CSS and add float:left. Try adjusting your screen size, they should be stacking neatly on top of one another.

```
@media screen and (max-width:650px) {
  .menu-small {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float:left;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nah, it still won't work.. I could remove the property of float: right; from right menu div using JS, but want it make done in css only.

Comment: So instead of float:left; I wrote float: right; and now they stacks neatly on each other, but only on the right side of the page. Now I need to figure out how to position them in the center, coz neither margin: 0 auto; and float: none; doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dneilsen22/wvLf18we/) that should be what you are looking for. Maybe I'm not understanding the original question, but we're only using CSS.

Comment: I would say that you build it as a neat vertical mobile menu first, then add CSS to re-size for desktop when you want that kind of functionality(i.e. splitting the menu to left and right of the page) next time.

Comment: I appreciate your time, but actually this is what I'm going for. Change view for full page and resize the page, you will see they start stacking on each other, but last two aren't aligned nicely. http://codepen.io/Limpuls/pen/qZqVvd

Comment: That's how I want it: horizontal navigation for desktop and vertical sitting on each other for mobile, I almost did that, but it's not sitting neatly on each other. I need to solve this problem...

Comment: I find it's an easier problem to solve going at it from this way. The vertical to the horizontal. Try this one https://jsfiddle.net/Dneilsen22/wvLf18we/2/